# is it possible to return all photos (in all sets) organized by set?

Tags: flickr

I've got a public flickr with multiple sets.

What I want to do is, with one API call, get all photos from all the sets but have each photo tagged by set.. is this possible?

I can only seem to find API calls that will get all photos for 1 set (flickr.photosets.getPhotos), or all photos in all sets (flickr.people.getPhotos) but can't seem to find one that will get all photos in all sets but somehow tag/id what set each photo belongs to...

possible?

thanks!

Comment: Does the original photos contains tags or you want to automatically tag the photos based on sets?

Comment: no tags... I don't mind adding tags, but which API call returns tags in the photo object? is it possible to automatically tag photos based on set?

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

1.get the list of sets for specific user by using

> flickr.photosets.getList

2.loop through all sets that the user has and get photos using

> flickr.photosets.getPhotos

3.Using

> flickr.photos.addTags

to add tags to all the photos in this set

Comment: with that solution, I really don't need the tags because I can just output the photos in the inner (step 2) loop, no?

Comment: Yes, but actually you can tag your sets and add tags to all photos in this set so you can simply use flickr.photos.search by userid and tags without the looping which increase performance